# How to install playonlinux on ubuntu

Tags: playonlinux

In the terminal, it tells me

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 playonlinux : Depends: curl
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please add more details. Also use formatting. You expect other people to help you?

Comment: You're having problems with broken packages.  Look at [How to fix Broken Packages](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how+to+fix+broken+packages).  There are lots of references to this on **AU**.  Many of the links in the list have accepted resolutions.  Try some of the ones that work and add more details to your question of where you experience problems.  Do as [Davidbaumann](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020893/how-install-playonlinux-on-ubuntu#comment1657648_1020893) mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing curl:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Then try installing playonlinux again.